# Search for words in a list filled with randomly put characters

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have a question:

If I would have a list of letters, let's fill it with:

```
A

T

C
```

I would want the algorithm to figure out which combinations creates words based off of a list of words I give it (they don't have to be the same length as the list's)

So from here it would go like this:

```
CAT, ACT, A etc etc.
```

What I'm having problems with is to understand how the basics of the algorithm should be.

Does anyone know how to help me start working on this?

Comment: are 2-letter words valid? and 1-letter?

Comment: Start with brute force approach.

Comment: @aleksey.berezan Yes. A word can have any length

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek Do you really think it's the best method? I do know that the max-number of characters in the list will be 16, but searching through a whole dictionary can be quite lengthy, when deleting words > 16 characters, still.

Comment: @Tokfrans - have you seen the question? "how to help me start working on this?" - MarcinJuraszek comment perfectly addresses that... If you have other requirement - please put into the question. Don't forget to add your own findings about the problem too while editing.

Comment: What I basically asked in the response to Marcin was if there were any other possible solutions you could use instead of brute-force since that would be quite time-consuming.

Comment: @Tokfrans: As it turns out, brute force isn't very time consuming. There aren't very many words in the English language (in computational terms). Always try the simple approach first - it can save a LOT of time and code complexity.

Comment: Can letters be repeated?  For example given "G  A T", would "GAG" be acceptable?

Comment: @MikeParkhill Letters may not be repeated

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is, of course, by brute force as has been mentioned. However, you don't want to be comparing random strings to your entire dictionary when many words will not be able to made with the letters you have. Here's a few tricks to help reduce your search space. I'm going to assume you're only looking at English words. If so, you can use some common language constructs to reduce your search space further. Now, bear in mind these probably won't catch *all* the words in the English language, but if you're putting together your own dictionary you can manually program in exceptions.

The first thing you will want to do is reduce your dictionary by removing all words that cannot be made given the search set. Loop through each letter and dictionary word and see if the word contains the letter. If not, remove it from the dictionary (this is a good candidate for using the Parallel library).

Next, start with your vowels. Every word has at least one and there is a fairly small number of ways they can be grouped. If you can't make a certain vowel grouping with your letters, get rid of any words containing that group. Also set your brute force generator to only look at valid vowel combinations.

A word that starts with 'h' will always(?) have a vowel as a second letter so don't join h(1) with anything except a, e , i, o, u or y.

i before e except after c, although that's such a small case I don't think it would be worth adding unless you're talking really long words.

Q is almost always followed by U.

Those few rules should really give you enough to reduce your search space by 90% or more. You then use grammar rules like the ones above to only generate combinations that are valid grammar which will reduce your space even further. After that, even with a large dictionary (100 000) words and 16+ characters, you should have a small enough search space to run a brute force algorithm in a decent time frame.

**The Not So Easy Approach**

If you really want to get fancy, you can use the Parallel library that I mentioned above to both speed up the reduction in search space and the brute force algorithm itself. Brute force is embarrassingly parallel so you'll get an almost linear improvement in run time if you throw more cores at it.

Beyond that, you can try using some Bayesian statistical analysis or a neural network to guide your combination choice, but that's probably overkill for what you're after :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your question right. If you want to know all the possible words that can be written with the characters in your list, you need a complete list of all words. One easy rule seems to be that each word must use only characters contained in the character list. This way you can find all possible strings that can be written with that character list:

```
List<char> characters = new List<char>() { 'A', 'C', 'T', 'F', 'B', 'O' };
List<string> dictionary = new List<string>() { "CAT", "ACT", "A", "FISH", "BONE" };
List<string> possibleWords = new List<string>();

foreach (string word in dictionary)
{
   if (!(word.ToLower().Except(characters.ToString().ToLower()).Any()))
   {
      possibleWords.Add(word);
   }
}

// Result: "CAT", "ACT", "A"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a starting point for you. It shows that in fact, brute force is just fine here. There are only about 200,000 words to check. The following algorithm takes only a few milliseconds for the full Scrabble word list, looking for matches in the first 16 letters of the alphabet:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var validWords = new List<string>(File.ReadAllText("AllWords.txt").Split(' '));

        foreach (var result in validWords.Where(word => 
                     IsWordInString(word, "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP")))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(result);   
        }
    }

    static bool IsWordInString(string word, string source)
    {
        var letterList = source.ToList();

        return word.All(letterList.Remove);
    }
}
```

The algorithm is:

- Iterate through the full list of valid words
- Check that every character in a word can be successfully 'struck out' of the valid character list
- If it can, it's a match. Otherwise, it's rejected.

Note - this is probably the simplest approach, and has *no optimizations* applied. There are many ways you could make this faster. But because its performance depends mostly on the length of the word list (which is constant), then increasing the list of letters has very little effect on the speed.

As a curiosity, if you run this (using the whole alphabet):

```
var longest = validWords.Where(word => 
    IsWordInString(word, "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"))
            .OrderByDescending(i => i.Length).First();
```

This instantly returns 'DERMATOGLYPHICS' - which is the correct longest word in the English language with no repeated letters. There's not noticeable execution time in my debugger.

(Word list from [here](http://www.becomeawordgameexpert.com/dictionary.htm))

Answer (score 0):

I think a brute force approach would be simplest. The algorithm is basically going to find every subset of your set of letters and check if it is in the dictionary. For each letter, it will check the possibility that it is in the word and not in the word.

Your dictionary data structure should be sorted so that whether or not a word is contained can be checked quickly using binary search (or you can use a hash set).

The pseudocode will look something like this:

```
A = array of letters
S = empty list

IS_VALID(word, i)
    //base case: reached the end of the letters
    if i > length(A) - 1
        return

    if dictionary contains word
        add word to S

    //check for all words containing A[i]
    IS_VALID(w + A[i], i+1)
    //check for all words excluding A[i]
    IS_VALID(w, i+1);

//initialization
IS_VALID("", 0)
```

where `word` is the string you are currently looking at and `i` is the index of the letter in `A` you are currently thinking of appending to the end of `word`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    private static bool b;

    /// <summary>
    /// Word with Random Characters
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="characterList"></param>
    /// <param name="wordList"></param>
    public static void WordWithRandomCharacters(List<char> characterList, List<string> wordList)
    {
        var resultWords = new List<string>();

        foreach (var word in wordList)
        {
            foreach (char c in word.ToCharArray())
            {
                b = false;
                if (characterList.Contains(c)) b = true;
                if (!b) break;
            }
            if (b) resultWords.Add(word);
        }

        foreach (var word in resultWords)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(word);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Add some explanation with your code please.